# what is the recommended practice for using feature modules in ng?

Tags: angular

What is the recommended practice for using feature modules in ng? I think I read on the angular.io site that using feature modules is considered best practice. If I "ng new" an app then an AppModule is created but this is just for bootstrapping the app. So can you describe how you would architect a new application with the use of modules? Please describe a basic sample app and how you would incorporate feature modules into the design as you're building it out

Comment: [This](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules) should paint a clear picture of what you are asking. The link includes additional link to examples.

Answer (score 1):

Feature Modules as the name suggest are generally developed based on Features in your Angular App. One of the major reasons for building a Feature Module is so that it could be Lazy Loaded.

Break your Angular App down into multiple logical segments. Each such segment can be implemented as a Feature Module. Although there would be some components/directives/pipes etc, that will be common in these feature modules. They can be exported as members of a Shared Module.

One thing to note down here is, none of the code from these feature modules should be directly imported into other modules if you're looking forward to make these modules as Lazy Loaded modules. Because doing that will load them instantly instead of loading them lazily.

You can read more about Module Segmentation in this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52028175/2622292) that I recently gave.

If you want to dive in-depth, consider reading more about [Feature Modules](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules)(as suggested by @r-richards), or about the rationale behind the Feature Modules on the official [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#feature-modules).