# module calling another module in angular 4/5/6?

Tags: angular

What is the best way of folder structure in angular for larger projects?

1) Can module call another module?, if so how many levels of sub modules can I have in one module.

2) can one sub module calls to another module which is part of another different module.

Comment: Have a look at `LazyLoading`

Comment: Have a look at [this StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52028175/2622292)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation the concept of lazy loading, it will https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules it will work

1) Can module call another module?, if so how many levels of sub-modules can I have in one module:- one module can easily call another module by applying the concept call lazy loading in angular 4/5/6 you can have n number of level you want to apply it up to you

2) can one sub-module calls to another module which is part of another different module:- yes it can call